# Wallet Misconfig

Tags: sql, oracle

I've configured a wallet as follows

1. Configured sqlnet.ora to include wallet directory
2. Access CDB$ROOT as sys and create Keystore using `ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT CREATE KEYSTORE '$ORACLE_HOME/wallet' identified by password;`
3. Closed the wallet using `ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE CLOSE IDENTIFIED BY password`

From my understanding, if I try to access the ORCL database, I should get an error saying the wallet is not open? But when I login using `sqlplus sys/orcl as sydba` I do not receive any error.

I am running the Oracle Developer DB VM if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the wallet OPEN, try to create a new table with a encrypted column, or create a tablespace with encryption then create/move tables to that tablespace.

Then, close the wallet and try querying from that table.

Encryptable objects (columns, tables, datafiles, tablespaces) have to be set as ENCRYPTed in order for TDE to apply.